# Zariski closure of a set in $k^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, zariski-topology

Let $k$ be any field, and we give $k^3$ the Zariski topology.

Then the question is how to compute the Zariski closure of the set $S=\{(x,y,z)\in k^3|xz=y, x+1=z^2, x\neq0\}$ in $k^3$.

The motivation is that I want to compute the blowup of the variety $\{(x,y)\in k^2|x^3+x^2=y^2\}$ at the point $(0,0)$.

Remarks: I have seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370450/how-does-one-find-the-zariski-closure-of-a-set?rq=1) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290037/zariski-closure-of-a-set-using-the-topological-definition-of-closure?rq=1). I also want more examples of computing the Zariski closure.

Merci beaucoup !

Comment: I assume you mean $k$ is any infinite field? If $k$ is finite then every set, including $S$ itself, is Zariski closed. For an infinite field, note that $S$ is just two points less than the clearly closed set $\{(x,y,z)\in k^3\colon xz=y,\, x+1=z^2\}$ (those two points being $(0,0,\pm1)$; does that suggest what the Zariski closure of $S$ might be?